# How to write data onto the image and preserve the padding for all the screen size using Flutter Stack?

Tags: image, text, flutter, stack

I have a credit card image and I need to write card details top of the credit card image. I can load the image and write a card details onto the image using Stack in flutter. But problem arise on different type of screen. The card details (Text) padding position will change on differ screen size.

How to write data onto the image  and preserve the padding for all the screen size using Flutter Stack?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps

Comment: @anmol it doesn't work on different screen size. The text padding off the stage on different screen size

Comment: @Nick have you solved that different screen size issue?
I'm having the same issue.